# Выбор определенного временного периода в Pandas (со всеми значениями в таблице)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо выбрать определенный период из .csv файла в котором несколько дней.

Пример данных, которые выводятся после фильтров из оригинального .csv файла

```
        ID         Period                d
0          1  2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   0.0
1          1  2019-08-10 07:45:00.000  10.0
2          1  2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   0.0
3          1  2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   2.0
4          2  2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   1.0
```

Необходимо из всей таблицы вывести все значения определенного дня (т.е. полных суток) 
от 2019-08-10 00:00:00.000  по 2019-08-10 23:59:59.000 или (2019-08-11 00:00:00.000).

Comment: `df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period']);
    df['Period'].dt.date.astype(str) == '2019-08-10'`

Comment: `df[df['Period'] >= pd.to_datetime('2019-08-10') & df['Period'] <= pd.to_datetime('2019-08-11')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример данных:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   ID                  Period     d
0   1 2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   0.0
1   1 2019-08-10 17:45:00.000  10.0
2   1 2019-08-10 23:59:59.999   0.0
3   1 2019-08-11 00:00:00.000   2.0
4   2 2019-08-11 20:20:00.000   1.0
```

Выбираем строки за нужный временной интервал:

```
In [55]: res = df.query("'2019-08-10' <= Period < '2019-08-11'")
```

Результат:

```
In [56]: res
Out[56]:
   ID                  Period     d
0   1 2019-08-10 07:45:00.000   0.0
1   1 2019-08-10 17:45:00.000  10.0
2   1 2019-08-10 23:59:59.999   0.0
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)